# speed up join between two databases

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have this query and takes 40 seconds, Is there a way to speed up? thank you

```
SELECT *, last.Date
FROM constant.derogation der             
LEFT JOIN variable.last last             
ON der.code = last.code
WHERE 1 = 1
AND status != 'removed'
ORDER BY status;
```

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | der   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    318 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | last  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 250950 | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

This is the structure of both tables, both databases are on the same server.
I will only get a value from Last Table

**DLL**

```
| derogation | CREATE TABLE `derogation` (
  `xxx` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` char(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `code_index_derogation` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


| Last | CREATE TABLE `Last` (
  `code` char(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxx` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxxx` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `xxxx` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_Last_Code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_Last_xxx` (`xxx`),
  KEY `code_index` (`code`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Show DDL for both tables. Show statistic by `status` column.

Comment: Please prepend each column with the table (or table alias) to identify where it's coming from. It may be obvious to you but not for us.

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Always name (and qualify) only the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: What is the relation of the 2 tables? Is it 1:1 or 1:n?

Comment: @forpas odd, I read status as belonging to last, but that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

you can use temporary tables, staging tables CTE or you can add indexes for the columns of the tables.
But using temporary tables, it's always an excelent choice to accelerate the excecution of the the SQL query.

Comment: It  was my first option, but It's  slower.

Comment: i am using python to query the table, so i didn't think in this option, but I probably use it. Thank you!

Comment: So please add Python as a tag in your question.

Answer (score 0):

(The problem is subtle, and often overlooked in this forum.)

Don't mix collations.  You are joining on `code`, but the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` are different between the two tables.  Suggest using `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO .. to get them to be the same.

Other tips:

- Use `CHAR` only for truly fixed-length columns.  Use `VARCHAR` otherwise.
- Have a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table.
- Don't say `LEFT JOIN` if you really expect `JOIN`; it adds confusion to the reader.